# needing code to use autofilter with variable range of rows

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I'm trying to autofilter data in a sheet with 7 columns before copying to another workbook. This is to be used on different data that will have a different number of rows each time. 
The issue is that when it autofilters the data it records the number of rows which is different each time (see Range("B1:B124")) below, which it will then apply the next time I try to use it

```
ChDir "F:\Work-Macro"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="F:\Work-Macro\usage.xls"
  Cells.Select
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 10
End With
Range("D:E,I:L").Select
Range("I1").Activate
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("A:F").Select
Range("F1").Activate
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    Range("B1:B124"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

there must be a way to apply the autofilter in a dynamic way without it recording the number of rows filtered

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a fixed range, you want to know the last cell that is in use:

`Range("B2:B" & ActiveWorkbook.sheets("Sheet1").cells(rows.count,2).end(xlup).row)`

The `ActiveWorkbook.sheets("Sheet1").cells(rows.count,2).end(xlup).row)` part will return the last row in use in column 2.

By the way, I suggest that you clean up your code after recording. Using `Select` and `Activate` is almost never necessary in a macro. It slows your code down and is very error sensitive.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for you reply and explanation (and advise to shorten the coding). I'm very new and trying to understand. I tried entering in your code and it comes up

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for you reply and explanation (and advise to shorten the coding). I'm very new and trying to understand. I tried entering in your code and it comes up Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range. Here is the code inserted  

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("B2:B" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
                                    Can you help with this? Thank you

Comment: Ah it needs to be Activeworkbook in this case instead of ThisWorkbook, since the code is in a different workbook than the filter.